# Proper way of reducing width of Angular Material's Tab labels?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

### The problem

Since `/deep/`, `>>>`, and `::ng-deep` are deprecated, what could be the correct way of reducing the width of `mat-tab-label` which has a min width of **160px** on desktop ?

- Without overriding it in the main `styles.css`
- I still want this custom styling of Material Tabs to be scoped to the parent component.

### Material spec statement

```
Fixed tabs display all tabs on one screen, with each tab at a fixed width.
The width of each tab is determined by dividing the number of tabs by the screen width.
They don’t scroll to reveal more tabs; the visible tab set represents the only tabs available.
```

However that's not entirely true, in my case, the `max-width` of my parent component is set to **320px** which roughly allow **106px** for each `mat-tab-label`.

#### Edit 1

The [Angular Material doc](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) advocate to `Add the overriding style to your global stylesheet. Scope the selectors so that it only affects the specific elements you need it to.` which is precisely what I wan to avoid because of separation of concerns

Comment: The idea of Material is creating an uniform UI, that will look / feel same across multiple instances. So, if you need to have a shorter labels in, say, your "notification-component" don't create a class for `.notification-tab` but for `.low-width-tab` or something similar. The odds are that if you need it in one place, you will need it later on. And that makes putting it in global .scss (personally I usually create file per component and then import it to styles.scss) logical - as long as you move from "styling a component" to "styling a feature".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up defining a custom styling of `MatTab` in the global `styles.css` :

```
your-component-selector {
  .mat-tab-label {
    min-width: 25px !important; // In addition to mat-strech-tabs allowing tabs to fill remaining space in parent container
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

- `your-component-selector` will do the scoping, custom styling won't bleed in other components `MatTab` instances.
- Don't forget to use `mat-stretch-tabs` on `<mat-tab-group>` in order to stretch Angular Material tabs to fit the parent width.

Comment: This is not working now. Need help about shortening the width.